# How publish data from multiple devices using a single connection to a broker

Tags: c, ibm-cloud, mqtt, iot, watson-iot

I'm working with a 6LowPan IPV6 network of connected devices (nodes) that forward their data to a border router which is connected to the internet. I'm trying to figure a way so that each node shows up in Watson IOT as a separate device. Is it possible to have more than one mqtt connection on the border router to the broker ?

Answer (score 0):

Each device connects to Watson IoT platform using the a client ID in a format such as this:  d:$org:$devicetype:$devicid  so each device would be connected with it's own unique ID.

Have you configured your router as a gateway?

If you are using your router as a gateway then it would connect with a g: instead of a d:  such as g:$org:$devicetype:$devicid
gateway can publish events from itself and on behalf of any device that is connected through the gateway.

Refer to [documentation](https://console.bluemix.net/docs/services/IoT/gateways/mqtt.html#mqtt) for more details.